# How to iterate over a function that takes an str and returns a String

Tags: rust

`my_function` is a function with signature `fn my_function(pos: &str) -> String`

```
fn main() {
  let mut my_str = "A";

  for _i in 0..1000 {
      my_str = my_function(my_str).as_str();
  }
  println!("{:?}", my_str);
}
```

I've been trying to implement this pattern but I am getting an error `temporary value is freed at the end of this statement`

[Link to Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=fn%20my_function(pos%3A%20%26str)-%3E%20String%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%22Hola%22.to_string()%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20my_str%20%3D%20%22A%22%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20for%20_i%20in%200..1000%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20my_str%20%3D%20my_function(my_str).as_str()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20my_str)%3B%0A%7D%0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using `String` the whole time:

```
fn main() {
  let mut my_str = "A".to_string();

  for _i in 0..1000 {
      my_str = my_function(&my_str);
  }
  println!("{:?}", my_str);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just store the string outside of the loop:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut my_str = "A";

    let mut owner: String;
    for _ in 0..1000 {
        owner = my_function(my_str);
        my_str = owner.as_str();
    }
    println!("{:?}", my_str);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

kmdreko's answer requires an extra initial allocation, Aloso's answer requires a separate variable to own the `String`, and both are fine answers. But for completeness, if your variable really needs to *sometimes* refer to borrowed data, and sometimes to owned data, you can use [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) (short for copy on write):

```
use std::borrow::Cow;

fn main() {
    let mut my_str = Cow::Borrowed("A");

    for _ in 0..1000 {
        my_str = Cow::Owned(my_function(&my_str));
    }
    println!("{:?}", my_str.as_ref());
}
```